# Unexpected token: StartObject, when deserializing OneOf union type using custom converter

Tags: c#, json.net

I am trying to deserialize the following JSON (which validates on https://jsonlint.com/):

```json
{"pandoc-api-version":[1,22],"meta":{"title":{"t":"MetaBlocks","c":[{"t":"Para","c":[{"t":"Str","c":"Dynamic"},{"t":"Space"},{"t":"Str","c":"Language"},{"t":"Space"},{"t":"Str","c":"Runtime"}]},{"t":"Para","c":[]}]}},"blocks":[{"t":"Para","c":[{"t":"Strong","c":[{"t":"Str","c":"Bill"},{"t":"Space"},{"t":"Str","c":"Chiles"},{"t":"Space"},{"t":"Str","c":"and"},{"t":"Space"},{"t":"Str","c":"Alex"},{"t":"Space"},{"t":"Str","c":"Turner"}]}]},{"t":"Para","c":[{"t":"Emph","c":[{"t":"Strong","c":[{"t":"Str","c":"Reading"},{"t":"Space"},{"t":"Str","c":"this"},{"t":"Space"},{"t":"Str","c":"Document:"}]}]}]}]}
```

into the following classes:

```cs
internal record TagContent(string T, OneOf<TagContent[], string>? C);

internal class RawPandoc {
    [JsonProperty] public int[] PandocApiVersion = default!;
    [JsonProperty] public Dictionary<string, TagContent> Meta = default!;
    [JsonProperty] public TagContent[] Blocks = default!;
}
```

using the following code:

```cs
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings {
    ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver { NamingStrategy = new KebabCaseNamingStrategy() },
    Converters = new JsonConverter[] { new OneOfJsonConverter() }
};
var pandoc = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RawPandoc>(s, settings);
```

and I get the following error:

**Unexpected token when deserializing object: StartObject. Path 'meta.title.c[0]', line 1, position 69.**

How can I resolve this?

---

For completeness, here is the current and incomplete code for `OneOfJsonConverter`. [OneOf](https://github.com/mcintyre321/OneOf) is a library for union types in C#:

```cs
using OneOf;

namespace PandocFilters {
    public class OneOfJsonConverter : JsonConverter {
        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object? value, JsonSerializer serializer) {
            if (value is IOneOf of) {
                value = of.Value;
            }
            serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
        }
    
        public override object? ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object? existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) {
            if (reader.Value is null) { return null; }
            // TODO not implemented yet
            return reader.Value;
        }
    
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => objectType.UnderlyingIfNullable().GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IOneOf));
    }
}
```

Comment: `OneOf<>` union types are fun for developers, but less so for deserializers.I don't think JSON.NET understands what you're trying to do, and your converter also doesn't, as it's _probably_ throwing somewhere after returning or instantiating `reader.Value`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is you are not advancing the reader in your `ReadJson` implementation. You declared your converter can handle `IOneOf` objects, and so JSON.NET expects your converter to actually read and handle it, however it does nothing as of now. So `ReadJson` is called (at the start of first array in json which should be deserialized to OneOf), and then after it returns - reader position is still where it was before (at start of array), which is not what JSON.NET expects. Then it fails trying to continue reading next object, because its assumptions are violated. So, just implement `ReadJson`, and meanwhile you can advance a reader for example like that:

```
public override object? ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object? existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) {
    // advance reader as expected
    var eitherStringOrArray = JObject.ReadFrom(reader);
    return reader.Value;
}
```

Comment: Probably a new question, but how do I produce a `TagContent` instance from the reader? When `JObject.ReadFrom(reader)` returns an instance of `JArray`; how do I proceed from there?

Comment: I think it's quite complicated to create general version of your converter, to work with any OneOf values. With this specific class it's easy, just check if it's JArray and if so - deserialize it to `TagContent[]` and return OneOf value with that. Otherwise it's should be a string, so do the same and return OneOf with string. But general case is much more complicated than that.